# Why does $\int_a^bf(x)\;\mathrm dx\;- \;\int_a^bg(x)\; \mathrm dx = \int_a^bf(x)-g(x)\;\mathrm dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

My teacher and I were going over some homework problems, specifically,

> Find the area bounded by the graphs of the curves $x^2$ and $2x$

My thinking was to set it up like this:

$$\int_0^22x \;\mathrm dx-  \int_0^2x^2 \; \mathrm dx =\frac 43 $$

This was the correct answer, but my teacher told me to set it up like this:
$$\int_0^22x-x^2\;\mathrm dx= \frac 43$$

I wasn't familiar with this "shortcut" and when I asked my teacher why it worked, he told me I should "figure it out."

So I set up the general case:
$$\int_a^bf(x)\;\mathrm dx\;- \;\int_a^bg(x)\; \mathrm dx = \int_a^bf(x)-g(x)\;\mathrm dx$$

From here I hit a block. I thought it might relate to the second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus but didn't find any obvious connections. If anyone could give me a step in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of the integral in terms of sums?

Comment: My understanding is that when we integrate, we are breaking up the large part into many small parts.

Comment: To add to @Chappers comment, the Riemann integral (which is presumably what you are using) is defined in terms of limits where the domain ($[a,b]$ above) is split into smaller parts (partitions). It follows from this that $\int (f+g) = \int f + \int g$. You can also show that $\int (\alpha f) = \alpha \int f$, where $\alpha$ is a scalar, so in fact, the integral in linear.

Comment: You can also relate it to an anti derivative version of the integral, and the result follows because differentiation is also linear in that $(f+g)' = f'+g'$.